# seeing garbled output with Popen communicate

Tags: python, linux

Am seeing garbled output with below code. Can someone help on how to synchronize the output?

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
def do_shell(cmd):
p = Popen('/bin/bash', shell=False, universal_newlines=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
o, e = p.communicate(cmd)
p.wait()
print('Output: ' + o.decode('utf8'))
```

Is it possible to wait for 5 sec after each command execution passed to communicate?
Note:Here cmd is string of commands (cmd=cmd1\ncmd2\ncmd3\n)

Comment: *You* might be seeing garbled output, but since we can't see it, it's kind of hard to even guess at what the problem is.  The only think I see that might be an issue is that you are ignoring STDERR; some commands may be sending part or all of their output there, instead of STDIN.

Comment: For example: am doing ls -l as command than my program exits and am seeing only half of the output.